# Using Context inside aidl service implementation

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-context

I'm trying to access sqlite DB (that is filled on diffrent part of the package) on AIDL stub implementation but - there is no context there. how can I get the context?
there are 2 projects (applications) - A,B.
Project A contains keeps records on sqlite DB. and contains aidl service.
Project B needs to ask project A (diffrent package, there can be many projects like B) if a record exists. the only way for project A to answer project B from the stub is to check the DB is to have a Context (the "?????" in the code below) - how can I get the project A's context from the stub?

The AIDL's implementation:

```
public class IRecordServiceImpl extends IRecordService.Stub{
    @Override
    public boolean RecordExists(String recordKey)
            throws RemoteException {
      boolean returnValue = false;
      RecordDataSource rds = new RecordDataSource(??????);
      rds.Open();
      returnValue = rds.isRecordExists(recordKey);
      rds.Close();
      return returnValue;
    }
}
```

The Service code:

```
public class IRecordService extends Service {

    private IRecordServiceImpl service;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            this.service = new IRecordServiceImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {      
        return this.service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - you can pass the `Service`'s `Context` via the constructor and keep it in `IRecordServiceImpl` as private field

Comment: Could you show me the code?

Comment: Actually, I don't have this code anymore. just add a context field to the IRecordServiceImpl constructor and pass the Context to it.

Comment: Anyway.Thk u...

Comment: It would be like that (sorry for doing it in comment, but there are too many pending edits, so I cannot edit the post)

class RecordService : Service() {
    private val serviceImplementation = IRecordServiceImpl(this.applicationContext)

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return serviceImplementation
    }
}